# javascript - How to get the value of variable as variable with window in an object

Tags: javascript, object, variables, window

```
key = 'first_name';
// This key might be anyting else
// key = 'last_name';
// key = 'age';
value = 'Ali';
// This value might be anyting else
// value = 'Jones';
// value = '50';
```

I want to send the value of an object using ajax like this:

```
key_value = {first_name: 'Ali'};
```

however the `first_name` above might change each time, so I tried:

```
key_value = {key: value};
```

however I want the value of key which is first_name in this example so I tried to use window

```
key_value = {window['key']: value};
```

But it throwed an error:

SyntaxError: missing : after property id

How can I fix this? THANKS

Comment: key_value[key] = value

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var key_value = {};
key_value[key] = value;
```

Snippet Example:

```js
var key = 'first_name';
var value = 'Ali';
var key_value = {};
key_value[key] = value;
console.log(key_value);
```

Comment: Thank You :) @RophitAgrawal

Comment: Glad to help @kodfire :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of shorthand property assignment in the object:

```js
var key = 'first_name';
var value = 'abc';
var key_value = {[key]:value};

console.log(key_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonVariable = {};
var key='first_name';
var value='Ali';

jsonVariable[key]=value;
```

Send `jsonVariable` through Ajax.

Comment: How is this different to Rohit's answer?

Comment: Because he answered before me  :-)